# Determine amount of text to put in a div to maximize width of last line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, algorithm

I made my own `csscolumn` (css3) polyfill script to break up text into two columns for readability. It's not a dynamic script that takes parameters, but is tailored to the site I'm working on right now.

It works fine except for one issue with the last line of text in the first column. In some cases only one word shows on the last line in column1 before the remaining text goes into the second column, where the sentence continues. In other words: too much whitespace in the sentence break between column1 and column2. Example:

```
Column 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,   sentence continued after break in first column.
consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do    etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc etc
sentence                                 etc etc etc etc etc etc etc.
```

I think this needs to be accomplished by using the `height`, `width` and `line-height` of each column (both will have same width, 49%).

My logic so far is:

- finding the middle index position in the string
- search for the next whitespace where the text will be split
- and then split the text on a whitespace approximately at the middle

I had no luck using existing polyfills for this problem. Then I used [Columnizer](https://github.com/adamwulf/Columnizer-jQuery-Plugin) where I encountered a bug that leaves the first column empty when I have a character count under 450. So I screamed out in my cubicle "F@** it!! We'll do it live!".
I don't want any horrible semantic either with `ul li` on simple article text.

But if there are better scripts out there for this problem then I'm open for that as an answer.

My simplified code:

```
$('.article-body').each(function (index) {
if ($(this).text().length > 300) {

  var text = $(this).text();
  var length = $(this).text().length;

  var col1 = null;
  var col2 = null;

  if (text[Math.floor(length/2)+14].trim() === '') {
    col1 = text.slice(0, Math.floor(length/2)+14).trim();
    col2 = text.slice((Math.floor(length/2))+15, length).trim();
  }
  else {
    loop1:
    for (var i = Math.floor(length/2)+14; i <= length; i++) {
      if (text[i].trim() === '') {

        col1 = text.slice(0, i).trim();
        col2 = text.slice(i+1, length).trim();

        $(this).empty();
        $(this).append("<div class='first-column'>"+col1+"</div>"); // Column 1
        $(this).append("<div class='second-column'>"+col2+"</div>"); // Column 2

        break loop1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know, that approach loses all formatting information of the text, including paragraphs, doesn't it? Wouldn't it be better to look at the paragraphs in the div and split at a paragraph break near the middle? In my experience, articles on the web consist of many small paragraphs. In a reasonably long article, the small difference in columns length shouldn't be an issue when breaking at paragraph breaks.

Comment: The problem is that a sentence breaks too early on the last line in column 1; before resuming in column 2. In other words: too much whitespace in the sentence break between column1 and column2.

Comment: I understand what your problem is. But I don't understand why you "flatten" the whole text with `.text()` and lose all formats.

Comment: There are no special formatting to take into account, like lists, links and images. They are meant as preview articles and links to full article pages are provided outside the article body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your article into words. Then create the two column divs and add the article text to the first measure the height. Then empty the first div and gradually fill it with words until the height of the div is about half the height of the column div with full content. Put all words up to the current one in the first div, the rest in the second.

This seems to work well, because the browser is doing the word-breaking. It works only for unresizable columns. It is fast enough I think, I've tested it with various article divs on one page. You can start neat the middle when checking for word-wrapping. (I realise the Mabedan's answer uses a similar approach, but it doesn't seem to account for words, just characters.)

Here's the code:

```
$().ready(function() {
  $('.article-body').each(function(index) {

    // get text as words
    var text = $(this).text();
    var words = text.split(" ");

    // prepare columns
    var col1 = $('<div class="first-column">');
    var col2 = $('<div class="second-column">');

    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append(col1);
    $(this).append(col2);

    // calculate div metrics
    $(col2).text(text);
    var height = $(col2).height();
    var middle = Math.ceil(0.5 * height);

    // fill col1 with words until it overflows
    var start = Math.floor(0.3 * words.length);
    var line = words.slice(0, start).join(' ');

    for (var i = start; i < words.length; i++) {
      var w = words[i];

      if (line) line += " ";
      line += w;

      $(col1).text(line);
      if ($(col1).height() > middle) {
          $(col1).text(words.slice(0, i).join(' '));
          $(col2).text(words.slice(i).join(' '));
          return;
      }
    }

    // not enough text: just fill col1
    $(col1).text(words.join(' '));
    $(col2).text('');

  });
});
```

Comment: This is how I would approach the problem. I'll add that you can absolutely position the column during the calculation with a negative left value (off screen) so that the user doesn't see the visual calculation, while you are still able to measure a height.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something like this, which is terrible. but might give you some ideas for further investigation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.setText = function () {
        var text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
            divs = $("div"),
            position  = Math.round(text.length / 2),
            divToEnlarge,
            initialFirstDivHeight,
            initialSecondDivHeight,
            incrementFactor;

        function setText() {
            divs.eq(0).text(text.slice(0, position));
            divs.eq(1).text(text.slice(position));
        }
        setText();
        initialFirstDivHeight = divs.eq(0).height();
        initialSecondDivHeight = divs.eq(1).height();

        divToEnlarge = initialFirstDivHeight > initialSecondDivHeight ? 1 : 0;
            incrementFactor = divToEnlarge === 0 ? +1 : -1;
        for (;;) {
            position += incrementFactor;
            setText();
            if (divs.eq(divToEnlarge).height() > initialFirstDivHeight) {
                position -= incrementFactor;
                setText();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
    button {
        display: block;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="document.setText()"></button>
<div></div><div></div>
</body>
</html>
```